# Relationship between representations of Lie groups and Lie algebras

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Consider all the finite-dimensional irreducible representations of a group.

1. For each finite-dimensional irreducible representation of a group, is there *one and only one corresponding* representation of the Lie algebra?
2. For a Lie group, are there always finite-dimensional irreducible representations of $n \times n$ matrices *for all values of $n$*?
3. For a Lie group, can there *only be one* finite-dimensional irreducible representation of $n \times n$ matrices *for each value of n*?

Comment: For 1, for non simply connected Lie groups, representations of the Lie algebra don't generally lift to the group. So I would say no.  Look for instance at $G=S^1$, $\frak{ g}=\mathbb{R}$ acting on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Every representation of a Lie group $G$ naturally induces a corresponding representation of the corresponding Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, by differentiation. I'm not sure how to interpret "only one" in this question.
2. No. For example, $SO(3)$ has irreducible representations only in odd dimensions $1, 3, 5, \dots$.
3. No. For example, $SU(2) \times SU(2)$ has two nonisomorphic irreducible $2$-dimensional representations, one for each of its factors.